# How can I add an animation to the activity finish()

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I'm using overridePendingTransition for when my activity is created and that works fine I can see the fade in works great, but when I try and animate the finish on the activity it is still doing the default right to left slide.

I first tried defining the out animation when I start the activity as follows:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(a, SkdyAlert.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    a.startActivity(myIntent);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
        AnimationHelper.overridePendingTransition(a, R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    }
```

Then I tried doing it when I finish the activity as well

```
okBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
                AnimationHelper.overridePendingTransition(activity, 0, R.anim.fadeout);
            }
        }
    });
```

But neither of these approaches will prevent the "right to left" slide for the exit animation.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

I override pending transition just after calling finish();

In my case, I have done it to avoid transitions.

```
finish();
Details.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nothing,R.anim.nothing);
```

Order is important :)

Comment: by "Details", @Goofyahead is naming his enclosing Activity--ymmv. This technique worked for me to replace an animation from Theme.Dialog on 2.x, but not 3.x or 4.x

Comment: How does `R.anim.nothing` look like?

Comment: Use @Felipe Micaroni Lalli answer, 0 mean no animation.

Comment: This like helped me too. It explains how to define your own animations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation

Comment: You can override `finish()` method to avoid transitions in all cases (back button pressed, as sample):
     `@Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }`

Comment: The above transition is executed only if enabled in Developer options, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30422015/2914140.

Answer (score 42):

This question has already answered but the most efficient way to put an animation while exiting from an activity is by overriding the "finish()" method of the related activity:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
}
```

Comment: This could be the accepted answer

Answer (score 26):

I would suggest to use isFinishing() method to configure the animations at onPause instead of calling finish()

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isFinishing()){
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_slide_in, R.anim.activity_slide_out);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is that better?

Answer (score 23):

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 20):

I fixed this issue using this kind of approach:

to open with animation:

```
 Intent newUser = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewUserActivity.class);
    startActivity(newUser);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

To close with animation:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    onBackPressed();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right,R.anim.slide_in_right);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Look into doing it through a theme.  You can define enter exit animations for activities or the entire application

Comment: YES! That was it. Well kinda. I had already applied a theme, and the theme had an animation defined, so thats why I couldn't get my own animation to work. Thanks a ton for the insight!

Comment: can you give me a hint where to look which transistions will be delivered by the themes. I also would like to set a custom transition to all sites but i don't know how.

Comment: @Zapnologica this other answer I gave for a similar question spells it out a bit more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940574/how-to-override-the-enter-activity-animation-if-it-is-stated-by-launcher/4940610#4940610

Answer (score 6):

Following on the answer by @schwiz, here is an animation override for the built-in Dialog theme, where I have defined local slide_up and slide_down animations. My activity specifies the theme MyDialog in order to have these transitions in and out.

```
<style name="Animation.MyDialog" parent="android:Animation.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.MyDialog</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use startActivityForResult to start your child activity and in onActivityResult() of your parent activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_YOUR_ACTIVITY) {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.parent_appearing_anim, R.anim.child_dissmissing_anim);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, arg2);
}
```

Comment: This works on back press (physical button). To make it also work with the "up" arrow, see this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161234/onactivityresult-is-not-called-when-the-back-button-in-actionbar-is-clicked/20161352#20161352](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161234/onactivityresult-is-not-called-when-the-back-button-in-actionbar-is-clicked/20161352#20161352)

Comment: Important to note: overridePendingTransition needs to be called before calling super.onActivityResult. Otherwise the pendint transition will not be overridden!