# Closing an activity animation

Tags: android, animation

I know how to stop animation on starting an activity:
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

How do I do I stop animation while closing an activity? (and returning to the starting activity)

Comment: Please refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330675/how-can-i-add-an-animation-to-the-activity-finish
Hope this will help you

Comment: or, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286315/disable-activity-slide-in-animation-when-launching-new-activity