# How to override the enter activity animation if it is stated by launcher

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, launcher

I tried to do Google search but I only found the solution for intra-activity animation using overridePendingTransition() method. However, is there any solution if I would like to have my own animation when my application is started by launcher?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 32):

You can define your animation with a custom theme.  Here is what you basically need.  Assuming you know how to use a theme, if not that is a separate question.  Below just delete any line you don't want to define your own animation for and it will fall back to the default android animation.

```
<!-- this goes in your theme -->
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyActivityAnimations</item>



<!-- Standard animations for a full-screen window or activity. -->
<style name="MyActivityAnimations" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_open_enter</item>
    <item name="activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/activity_open_exit</item>
    <item name="activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_close_enter</item>
    <item name="activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/activity_close_exit</item>
    <item name="taskOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/task_open_enter</item>
    <item name="taskOpenExitAnimation">@anim/task_open_exit</item>
    <item name="taskCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/task_close_enter</item>
    <item name="taskCloseExitAnimation">@anim/task_close_exit</item>
    <item name="taskToFrontEnterAnimation">@anim/task_open_enter</item>
    <item name="taskToFrontExitAnimation">@anim/task_open_exit</item>
    <item name="taskToBackEnterAnimation">@anim/task_close_enter</item>
    <item name="taskToBackExitAnimation">@anim/task_close_exit</item>
    <item name="wallpaperOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_open_enter</item>
    <item name="wallpaperOpenExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_open_exit</item>
    <item name="wallpaperCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_close_enter</item>
    <item name="wallpaperCloseExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_close_exit</item>
    <item name="wallpaperIntraOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_open_enter</item>
    <item name="wallpaperIntraOpenExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_open_exit</item>
    <item name="wallpaperIntraCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_close_enter</item>
    <item name="wallpaperIntraCloseExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_close_exit</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @hackbod there's really no need to recommend anything here.... The guy here provided the only answer on stackoverflow to the question! For me it was the "recommended" answer...

Comment: These attributes appear to be missing a `android:` namespace.