# How do I Change the default animation when changing activity?

Tags: android, animation, button, android-activity, homescreen

Hello I have an application which I can touch to scroll across several screens like the [Android Homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969226/android-homescreen) app.

I have now managed to add a button on each page which changes from this to a new activity, but the scrolling is left to right and I want it to scroll down when the button is clicked but I can't figure out how to do it.

(This is probably a very noob question - sorry for that.)

Here is my main.java file

```
public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button onebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsone);
        onebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series1button.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});


        Button twobutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundstwo);
        twobutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series2button.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});  
        Button threebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsthree);
        threebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series3button.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});        Button fourbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsfour);
        fourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series4button.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});        Button fivebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsfive);
        fivebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series5button.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});        Button sixbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundssix);
        sixbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series6button.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});        Button sevenbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundsseven);
        sevenbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series7button.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});        Button eightbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.soundseight);
        eightbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main.this, series8button.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may refer to the [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Animation.html) in apidemos's directory, which uses `overridePendingTransition` to show custom animation. Also another post related to this topic: [Can I change the Android startActivity() transition animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515264/can-i-change-the-android-startactivity-transition-animation)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Android theme API see my answer here [How to override the enter activity animation if it is stated by launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940574/how-to-override-the-enter-activity-animation-if-it-is-stated-by-launcher/4940610#4940610)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good sample. Its great and smooth.I tried. One of answers : [Activity transition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android)