# Change Activity's default exit animation

Tags: android, android-layout

For my live wallpaper I want to change the exit animation for the settings activity. By default, when exiting the activity, it simultaniously scales down to the center and fades out. I want it to just fade out, with no resizing involved.

I've tried defining my own animation settings in `styles.xml`. Setting `android:windowExitAnimation` to `@android:anim/fade_out` does not seem to do what I want. The animation still scales down before it is faded out. I've tried countless of other animation settings, such as `android:activityCloseExitAnimation`, but none of them seem to get rid of the resizing behaviour I explained above.

Also, `overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.abc_fade_out);` has the same result: the activity still scales down when exiting.

Is there any way to override this default animation behaviour, so that the exit animation doesn't involve resizing?

If not, is it possible to entirely remove the exit animation, so that the application dissapears instantly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should try to override the `finish` method inside your `Activity` as follows:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I still have one question though. What if I wanted to set the **enter** animation using `overridePendingTransition`? Where should I do that?

Comment: Using this method, I think you can try to call it in onCreate or onStart (see the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)), but I don't know if you will have the expected result. However, you could also use a [custom animation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4940610/2668136) from your style. @RuudLenders

Comment: Currently I'm using a *custom animation* for the **enter** animation, and the *code* you wrote above for the **exit** animations. It works like I want it to, but it feels wierd using different methods for the enter/exit animation. I will try overriding `onCreate` or `onStart`.

Comment: You were right, the enter animation can be overridden in `onCreate`.

Comment: Yes, good to know. You can also do the same in `onResume` method. Good coding.