# How to open Android Activitys without animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I've programmed an android App, everything works fine, exept for one thing: when i switch from one activity to another, it makes this "activity opens" animation, you know, when it opens like a new app. Is there any way to open an activity without that Animation? Thanks

Comment: Use Fragments, they are better suited for your needs. More details [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to use a `Flag` with your `Intent` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
```

But keep in mind:

> If set in an Intent passed to *Context.startActivity()*, this flag will prevent the system from applying an activity transition animation to go to the next activity state. **This doesn't mean an animation will never run -- if another activity change happens that doesn't specify this flag before the activity started here is displayed, then that transition will be used.** This flag can be put to good use when you are going to do a series of activity operations but the animation seen by the user shouldn't be driven by the first activity change but rather a later one.

Or you can define a [custom animation in your style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940610/2668136) with `@android:style/Animation.Activity` parent as `@null` parameter for the animations that you do not want.

Answer (score 3):

After starting intent you can use:

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

To remove any animation. First parameter goes for animating opening activity and second for activity that is moved back. Both refer to anim resource

Comment: Adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION helped for all activities except home activity. This command fixed it.