# overridePendingTransition for the entire App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, android-animation

Is there a way to set a custom animation for the entire app (i.e. at the app level), without writing a custom class, etc which will affect the entire app? i.e. whenever an activity is starting within or from my app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4940610/2444099

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, if written as answer I'll accept it