# Android Left to Right slide animation

Tags: android, animation

I have three activities whose launch modes are single instance.
Using `onfling()`, I swing them left and right.

The problem is when I swipe right to left the slide transition is okay but when I swipe left to right, I get the transition of swiping right to left.

I know why this is happening its because I am always sending new intents. But, now I need to change the animation of sliding left to right.

I know there is a method named `overridingTransitionPending()`, but I do not know how to define my animation in XML.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what did you use to hold the activities until you swiped?

Comment: a bit late but you can use a simply hold.xml file that has 0% for all of the deltas

Answer (score 438, accepted):

Use this xml in `res/anim/`

This is for left to right animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

This is for right to left animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

In your coding use intent like for left to right:

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter,
                   R.anim.animation_leave);
```

In your coding use intent like for right to left

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_leave,
                               R.anim.animation_enter);
```

Comment: Any chance we can use android.view.animation.Animation in Java instead of defining it in XML?  I already use the Animation class for my ViewFlipper, and I would like to reuse it for overrideTransitionPending().

Comment: can I give animation an image?I am decrypting an image and setting it in a image view I want to change it in each fling I want the image to be set with the effect is it possible?

Comment: I know it's an old question but I have to ask: what if I want to use these with fragment transactions? I thought that it would be as trivial as calling `trans.setCustomAnimations(Res.a, Res.b);` with "trans" being the FragmentTransaction. But for some reason it doesn't work :( The fragments just appear without any animation what so ever. Do you have any idea why this is? You seem to know something about animations :P Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried this in a hobby project that I am working on, and it works great! Is there some way to externally set variables like duration, easing etc. when working with xml-based animation?

Comment: short and sweet solution it is

Comment: Which file above is animation_leave.xml and animation_enter.xml?

Comment: how to make infinite loop for this animation?

Comment: Thanks. I noticed a problem though; for the right-to-left animation you swapped XDelta values. Should be android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"

Comment: Beautiful. just  val intentGoToMenu = Intent(this, DailyProgAct::class.java)
            startActivity(intentGoToMenu)
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left, R.anim.right);

Answer (score 175):

If you want the transition work for whole application you can create a `rootacivity` and inherit it in the activity you need. In Root Activity's onCreate call `overridePendingTransition` with desired direction. And `onStart` call `overridePendingTransition` with other direction if activity is resumed. Here I am giving full running code below.Correct me if I am wrong.

create this xml file on your anim folder

**anim_slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

**anim_slide_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

**anim_slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

**anim_slide_out_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

**RootActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RootActivity extends Activity {
    int onStartCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onStartCount = 1;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) // 1st time
        {
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
        } else // already created so reverse animation
        { 
            onStartCount = 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        if (onStartCount > 1) {
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right,
                    R.anim.anim_slide_out_right);

        } else if (onStartCount == 1) {
            onStartCount++;
        }

    }

}
```

**FirstActivity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstActivity extends RootActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tv.setText("First Activity");
        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**SecondActivity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends RootActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tv.setText("Second Activity");
        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**ThirdActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ThirdActivity extends RootActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tv.setText("Third Activity");
        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        bt.setText("previous");
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

and finally 
**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.transitiontest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.transitiontest.FirstActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.transitiontest.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.transitiontest.ThirdActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I know this is a really old post, however, I cannot for the life of me get the onUpNavigation to load the right to left slide animation (after the activity has been created). Everytime, no matter what, it does the left to right animation. Anyone have any ideas???

Comment: this solution may crash folks, we have to use objectAnimator please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760299/android-fragmenttransaction-custom-animation-unknown-animator-name-translate

Comment: That answer should be the accepted one. It's really understandable and works great

Comment: the slide in amination should be the othe way around slide_in_left.xml -100 -> 0 slide_in_right.xml 100-> 0

Answer (score 78):

> **If you want to apply the animation on "*activity*" start. then write below code.**

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.opening_anim, R.anim.closing_anim);
```

> **If you want to apply the animation on "*dialog*" then firstly add below code in `styles.xml` file**

```
<style name="my_style”> 
 <item 
  name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/opening_anim</item> 
 <item 
 name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/closing_anim</item>
</style>
```

**Use this style as I defined below.**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.my_style;
```

> **If you want to apply the animation on "*view*" then write below code**

```
txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
     
// load the animation
Animation animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.animation); 

// start the animation
txtMessage.startAnimation(animFadein);
```

> **Below, I have mentioned most of the animation `.xml` code.**

## appear - make it just appear.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1"
           android:fromAlpha="1.0"
           android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
</set>
```

===========================================

## make it slowly fades into view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="300"
        android:repeatCount="0" />
</set>
```

==========================================

## fadeout - make it slowly fade out of view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="300"
        android:repeatCount="0" />
</set>
```

==========================================

## push_down_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

==========================================

## push_down_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

==========================================

## push_left_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

==========================================

## push_left_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

==========================================

## push_right_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

==========================================

## push_right_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

==========================================

## push_up_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

==========================================

## push_up_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

==========================================

## rotation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="-90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="0" android:fillAfter="true">
</rotate>
```

==========================================

## scale_from_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromYScale="0" android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fromXScale="0" android:toXScale="1.0" 
        android:duration="500" android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="100%" />
</set>
```

==========================================

## scale_torwards_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0"
        android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0" 
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

==========================================

## shrink_and_rotate_a(exit).xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.8"
    android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.8"
    android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="100"
/>
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="150"
    android:startOffset="100"
/>
```

==========================================

## shrink_and_rotate_b(entrance).xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="150"
    android:startOffset="250"
/>

<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.8" android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.8" android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="100"
    android:startOffset="400"
/>
```

========================================

## blink.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:duration="800"
      android:repeatMode="reverse"
      android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

========================================

## ZoomIn.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="1000"
       android:fromXScale="1"
       android:fromYScale="1"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:toXScale="3"
       android:toYScale="3" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

========================================

## ZoomOut.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="1000"
       android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="1.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:toXScale="0.5"
       android:toYScale="0.5" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

========================================

## FadeIn.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true" >
    <alpha
       android:duration="1000"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

========================================

## FadeOut.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true" >
    <alpha
       android:duration="1000"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

========================================

## Move.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
   android:fillAfter="true">
   <translate
       android:fromXDelta="0%p"
       android:toXDelta="80%p"
       android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

========================================

## SlideDown.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
       android:duration="800"
       android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="0.0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

========================================

## SlideUp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
       android:duration="800"
       android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="1.0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>
```

========================================

## Bounce.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fillAfter="true"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
    <scale
       android:duration="800"
       android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="0.0"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: My pleasure! @VishrutMavani

Comment: Nice collection of animations!

Comment: I just upvote this answer because of the efforts of @PrinceDholakiya

Answer (score 71):

Made a sample code implementing the same with slide effects from left, right, top and bottom.
(For those who dont want to make all those anim xml files :) )

Checkout out the code on [github](https://github.com/habibm/Android/tree/master/CustomActivityTransition)

Answer (score 16):

Also, you can do this:

```
FirstClass.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

And you don't need to add any animation xml

Comment: Transition is kind of slow. Any way to make it faster without adding any animation file?

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to find any solution for this type of animation using ViewPropertyAnimator.

Here's an example:

**Layout:**

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/child_view_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/child_view"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Animate - Right to left and exit view:**

```
final childView = findViewById(R.id.child_view);
View containerView = findViewById(R.id.child_view_container);
childView.animate()
  .translationXBy(-containerView.getWidth())
  .setDuration(TRANSLATION_DURATION)
  .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
  .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

**Animate - Right to left enter view:**

```
final View childView = findViewById(R.id.child_view);
View containerView = findViewById(R.id.child_view_container);
childView.setTranslationX(containerView.getWidth());
childView.animate()
    .translationXBy(-containerView.getWidth())
    .setDuration(TRANSLATION_DURATION)
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            childView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can I show from right to left? Because your Animate - Right to left and exit view hides the content to left. My target is to show it from right to left

Answer (score 2):

If your API level is 19+ you can use `translation` as above.
If your API level is less than 19, you can take a look at similar tutorial: http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/

Answer (score 2):

**For from right to left slide**

res/anim/in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shareInterpolator="false">
   <translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

res/anim/out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shareInterpolator="false">
   <translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

in Activity Java file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ActivityCapture.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in,R.anim.out);
```

you can change the duration times in the xml files for the longer or shorter slide animation.