# Android - vertical scrolling?

Tags: android, scroll, textview

Can anyone tell me how I might achieve automatic vertical scrolling of multiple TextViews?

I currently have a list like this :

```
TextView 1
TextView 2
TextView 3
TextView 4 
TextView 5
```

I need to show one TextView at a time in view and scroll vertically with a short delay in between each transition, then loop back to the beginning of the list..

I've tried the marquee feature of TextView and it does not allow vertical scrolling, I also tried a custom implementation of a vertical scroller but it was not flexible enough for my needs.

It is important to nest TextView controls inside so I can colour the text on each one programatically.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean scrolling the text through the view, or scrolling the entire view so that the position of the TextViews are changed?

Comment: I think I need the container to scroll so the TextView positions are changed if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put those TextViews in a ViewFlipper and assign proper in- and out-animations for it with .setInAnimation(...) and .setOutAnimation(...), or use the respective xml attributes. You need animations that translate the contents of the ViewFlipper. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation) thread, you can check out how to create translate animations.

ViewFlipper can also flip the child views automatically, or you can use the manual way by calling .setDisplayedChild(...), read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).

Answer (score 2):

Besides what **Zsombor Erdődy-Nagy** already said there is a working example in the android samples `Api Demos` in [`Views/Animation/Push`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Animation2.html).