# How to Reverse Fragment Animations on BackStack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, back-stack

I thought the system would reverse animations on the backstack when the back button is pressed when using fragments using the following code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.hyperspace_out);
ft.replace(R.id.viewContainer, new class(), "layout").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 275, accepted):

According to the [android documentation for custom animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

Change:

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.hyperspace_out);
```

To:

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.hyperspace_out, R.anim.hyperspace_in, R.anim.slide_out );
```

and now the backstack animates - In reverse!!

Comment: btw, I know this isn't connected to your question and answer, but could you maybe link me to something that explains customAnimations a little bit? :P

Comment: AreusAstarte: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int, int, int, int)

Comment: Hi im actually using Content transition, is working fine, but when  i press back and go to previous fragment the background just disapear animateing the views but also overlying with the prevoious ones, any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 24):

Use the Correct animation 
I have used the following and its working like a charm

**slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="1000"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1000"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-1000"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

**slide_out_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="-1000"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Then Use following while adding fragment

```
setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                                R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_right)
```

and it will worked 100%

Comment: Note this will not work if you are using the support fragment manager or if your fragment extends the support version of Fragment

Comment: @w3bshark How to get such animations working using `FragmentManager` and `Fragment` from support library?

Comment: @DanielShatz You must use translations rather than objectAnimators. For instance, slide_in_left.xml would be: `<translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:startOffset="25" android:toXDelta="0" />` See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5151774/1738090

Comment: I am trying this out (on Marshmallow device - didnt try other versions). It doesnt work.          final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left,
                R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right); fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_right_container, detailFragment); fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_left_container, subcategoriesFragment, TestActivity.TAG_SUBCATEGORIES_FRAGMENT);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

Answer (score 14):

in my case

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, 
                       R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

would create perfect animation.

**slide_in_right**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_left**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: I thought of doing it my self, but I am too lazy. And I said somebody should have post this on StackOverflow and here it is! haha

Comment: Nobody had posted this before and I quite believed that time was my turn to post this answer, to help s.o who might be in the same shoes as me... lol @F.Mysir

Answer (score 3):

```
.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_fade_in,
        R.animator.fragment_fade_out,
        R.animator.fragment_fade_p_in,
        R.animator.fragment_fade_p_out)
```

Replace the above with:

```
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_fade_in,
            R.animator.fragment_fade_out,
            R.animator.fragment_fade_p_in,
            R.animator.fragment_fade_p_out)
    .replace(R.id.main_container, FragmentPlayerInfo.getInstance(data))
    .addToBackStack(FragmentPlayerInfo.TAG)
    .commit();
```

Comment: I would recommend you to add an explanation on how your recommendation helps.

Comment: I do not know why it work (: , but when added animation after `replace` and `addToBackstack`, is not worked

Comment: @TarikW i'm bit late, but order is important in this, you need to call setCostomAnimations before replace, addToBackStack methods

Answer (score 1):

This is as mentioned in Fragment Transaction class .

```
/**
     * Set specific animation resources to run for the fragments that are
     * entering and exiting in this transaction. The <code>popEnter</code>
     * and <code>popExit</code> animations will be played for enter/exit
     * operations specifically when popping the back stack.
     *
     * @param enter An animation or animator resource ID used for the enter animation on the
     *              view of the fragment being added or attached.
     * @param exit An animation or animator resource ID used for the exit animation on the
     *             view of the fragment being removed or detached.
     * @param popEnter An animation or animator resource ID used for the enter animation on the
     *                 view of the fragment being readded or reattached caused by
     *                 {@link FragmentManager#popBackStack()} or similar methods.
     * @param popExit An animation or animator resource ID used for the enter animation on the
     *                view of the fragment being removed or detached caused by
     *                {@link FragmentManager#popBackStack()} or similar methods.
     */
    @NonNull
    public abstract FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations(@AnimatorRes @AnimRes int enter,
            @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int exit, @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int popEnter,
            @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int popExit);
```

so finally you can use method like this

```
 mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left,//enter
                                             R.anim.slide_out_left,//exit
                                             R.anim.slide_right,//popEnter
                                             R.anim.slide_out_right)//popExit
                        .addToBackStack(fragment.toString())
                        .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me!! this code for fragment! if you want to use this code in activity, delete at the beginning `getActivity()`!!

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.fade_out,android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.fade_out)
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new YourFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Good luck to you!!