# Fragment Animation for addToBackStack

Tags: android-fragments

How to set animation when we are using addToBackStack() in fragment ?

My old fragment need to be stayed up and new fragment to should overlap the old fragment with animation and show it to user.

I tried setCustomAnimation(). But i can't.

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886669/how-to-reverse-fragment-animations-on-backstack

Answer (score 1):

When you are about to add the fragment you can use the FragmentTransaction class to set the animation.

So something like this...

```
FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

    ft.add(android.R.id.content,fragment ,TAG);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

This should lay your current fragment on top of anything else without removing anything. The "setTransition" animation will animate the fragment entrance but I would make an attempt to use "setCustomAnimations" to get full control of how the fragment will be animated.

Comment: `setTransition` doesn't accept value of `TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK`. 
From the docs: 
`Select a standard transition animation for this transaction. May be one of TRANSIT_NONE, TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN, TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE, or TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE.`
`