# android error: "commit already called" when remove a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to implement an activity that has a fragment! when I click on Fragment1 , Fragment2 is called , and when I click on Fragment2 , Fragment2 should be removed from the screen!
I implement it by calling setOnclickListener of LinearLayout of Fragment2 in its onCreateView , and on my onclicklistener , I called

`transaction.remove(myFragment);`

`transaction.commit();`

but after that I faced to this error : commit already called
how can I fix this error , here is my code:
It is my fragment class

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
int mCurrentPosition = -1;
private static LinearLayout l;
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction;
private Fragment newFragment;

public void setArticleFragment(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction , Fragment newFragment) {
    this.transaction = transaction;
    this.newFragment = newFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container , false);
    l = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.transparentArea);
    if(l == null)
    l.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            transaction.remove(newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
}
```

and my mainAcitivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{

HeadlinesFragment firstFragment;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

    } else {
        final ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        newFragment.setArticleFragment(transaction, newFragment);

        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slidein, R.anim.slideout);
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of reusing the passed-in transaction, create a new `FragmentTransaction` instance that removes Fragment2.

Even easier is to add the first fragment transaction to fragment back stack (e.g. `addToBackStack(null)`) and then in Fragment2, just pop the back stack with `FragmentManager` `popBackStack()`.

Comment: And how to add animation to remove fragment 2 in this methods??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886669/how-to-reverse-fragment-animations-on-backstack

Answer (score 3):

Begin new transaction

```
fragTran = fragMan.beginTransaction();
fragTran.replace(R.id.frag_cont_two, fThree);
fragTran.addToBackStack(null);
fragTran.commit();
```

Comment: Your code is not work when i have many button to open different fragment

Comment: You have to replace different fragment with the different condition. Please read concept of fragment

Comment: I have also one problem @AnandSavjani when I am click on other button it alwayes crshed Application and Generate exception in commit is already called

Comment: add your `fragTran = fragMan.beginTransaction();` line everytime when you click on button

Comment: This is not work and when i am click on another button Previous Data is not clean  new data is comes in Previous data

Comment: @AshishShahi : Read for fragment transaction so you will get clear idea about it

Comment: I am already done this job but you say that is not properly work . I am ask you because i am waste too much time in Your Code so I am asking another wise no any problem.   Thanks For Your Responce

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue 
after calling `commit()` and again replacing the fragment you should start from

```
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Comment: add  fragmentTransaction .addToBackStack(null);