# How to set slide out as return transition

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm unable to set return transition between fragment when back button pressed fragment just closed abruptly without smooth slide out transition, here is what I'm trying:

```
DetailsFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailsTransition());
DetailsFragment.setReturnTransition(new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT));
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886669/how-to-reverse-fragment-animations-on-backstack) could help you.

Comment: not reverse just different set of animation

Answer (score 0):

According to FlyingNades answer, if you need animation for exiting case you set enter animation to 0 or default animation, like:

`fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(0, R.anim.my_exit_animation);`

If your fragment still continue to close abruptly, then you may have issue with backstack. You can also give animation for popping from back stack case, like:

`fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(0, R.anim.my_exit_animation, 0, R.anim.my_backstack_pop_exit_animation);`

Comment: there is difference between transition and applying animation like this