# Animate view to new location after another view setVisibility(GONE)

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to show 3 `Views` in my layout, but only 2 at a time. When I press a button, I want the most left view to slide out to the left, the middle one to slide with it, taking the start space of the left view, and the most right view should slide into the screen.

Here are some screenshots:

Before animation:
[image]

During animation (paint edit ^^):
[image]

After animation:
[image]

This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/stations_stations"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/fragment_border" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/stations_singlestation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/fragment_border" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/stations_trip"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/fragment_border"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So I am able to animate the lefmost view out of the screen using the code below:

```
    final View stationsContainer = findViewById(R.id.stations_stations);
    Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    stationsContainer.startAnimation(an);
    an.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            stationsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

This animates the leftmost view out of the window to the left, and sets it to gone. I can also animate the middle view to the new location, but when the animation is done, the middle view jumps back to its original position for a very short time, after which it takes the correct position. How can I avoid this jumping?

Comment: I think you could use LinearLayout and then on press of the button set the first one's visibility to View.GONE. Then when you want it back you would set it back to View.VISIBLE.

Dunno, how that would work with animations, though.

Comment: That is indeed what I have now, but it's not a pretty sight.

Comment: Try to play around with
[TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

Comment: Since you are not actually showing the code that is causing you problems, it will be difficult for anyone to really help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use the [`LayoutTransistion`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html) class to automatically animate child views whenever their visibility changes between `VISIBLE` and `GONE`. This class is available from `API 11` onward.

  For sample code, check out  samples that come with the sdk. Exact path is `ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\animation\LayoutAnimationsHideShow.java`
- Use [`LayoutAnimationController`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html) class to animate the views when they are added to and removed from a viewgroup. Here you have to hold a reference to a removed view, as you want to add it again later. This class is available in all versions of Android.

  Sample code path :`ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view\LayoutAnimation`

Comment: Brilliant. I'm using the `LayoutTransition` class, the only thing you have to do is `setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition())`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `animation` to slide in and out. you will need to define animation as xml in your resources.

[See this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)

Or you can use a `ViewFlipper`
[Try this as an example](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html)

There are plenty more examples on SO and web.

Answer (score 0):

Add your FrameLayouts into a ViewFlipper. e.g.

```
<ViewFlipper>
 <FrameLayout1/>
 <FrameLayout2/>
 <FrameLayout3/>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Then in your code call setInAnimation(leftInAnim) and setOutAnimation(leftOutAnim) to the viewFlipper, and call showNext(), which will cause animations to be applied to the current view and the next view.

leftInAnim and leftOutAnim is an XML animation resource that tells the system how to animation current view: e.g.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

This will cause a view to slide in from the right (out of view) into current view

Comment: But can I show 2 Views at once as well? Now the Views just appear on their own.

Comment: I've edited my question. I think `ViewFlipper` is not exactly what I need

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `android:animateLayoutChanges=true` to `LinearLayout` that hold all the views, you will get desired result