# Slider in Android

Tags: android

I am currently developing an android application with Eclipse. I would like to be able to slide in or out in order to go to next screen(Activity). Does anyone have any idea of how to create this control or any 3rd party to do this?

Thanks,

Charles

Comment: You have to use Animations for an Activity for sliding and moving to other activity. Check the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) is the class you will need to use and [here](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/29/android-switching-screens-by-dragging-over-the-touch-screen/) is a nice tutorial explaining how you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Google generally encourages the use of the "back" button for navigation, rather than other on-screen controls. Albeit, it may be appropriate in some cases, so do not be discouraged from putting in your own Activity controls if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
out_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:progress="50"
                android:progressTint="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Progress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>  

Java
```