# Sliding pages in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewflipper

I'm working on an application and let's say I have 5 different layouts plus a main layout which has links to each layout. In the main layout when the user click to the first button it is suppose to go the related layout by sliding. And It's same for other views.

When the user goes to one of these layouts, the next layout also has a couple of links to other layouts as like a chain. And this chain is moving from layout to the other one by sliding.

I have tried to do this with view flipper but since I have so many different layouts and they have background images and some contents in it, I get out of memory error.

So I'm trying to find a solution in this manner. Any idea how to accomplish this ?

Comment: how about the Out of memory issues ? Does it solve this issue ?

Comment: It loads 3 pages at one time. I'm using it my app with about 200 pictures and its working fine.

Comment: I also used it in one of my applications, but it was also for images.
one more thing, do you know that are we able set in and out animations for sliding ? not with finger it must be with click operations.

Comment: Yes we can, there are tutorials on it aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Jake Whartons [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/):

Create a `Fragment` for every of your Layouts and set the layout to your Fragment with the `onCreateView()` methode inside your fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
    }
```

Now create a `FragmentPagerAdapter` there sould be a methode called `getItem()`. `Switch` the Position and set it to your Fragment:

```
 public Fragment getItem(int position) {
 switch(position)
       {
               case 0:
                    TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();  
                    return fragment;

                case 1:
                    TestFragment2 fragment2 = new TestFragment2();  
                    return fragment2;

         }

                    DefaultFragment fragment3 = new DefaultFragment();  
                    return fragment3;

         }
```

Now you should be able to swipe to your Layouts(Fragments) easily

Comment: I will try something in this way and let you know if it works for my situation.

Comment: I tried the way with fragments but not with ViewPager and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new `android.app.Activity` hosting each layout and override the transitions between activities using `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_leave, R.anim.animation_enter);` where *.anim.animation_leave and _enter are neatly already spec'ed out for you in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5151774/1348379).

You can write the overridePendingTransition code immediately after your call to start the 'chained' activity and (if required) the reverse effect can be applied by providing the opposing transitions after calling `finish()` on the Activity or selecting the 'Up' navigation button press or 'back-button' press.

Having a single activity manage one layout will (in my experience) also benefit code maintainability.

Comment: This page that I want to design will be one of the tabs. so If start a new activity, it will make the things more complicated. thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I see... Sorry, didn't realise this was under the context of a tab. Re: the ````ViewPager```` suggestions with that in mind - having a view pager under a tab sounds bad. It's essentially two forms of lateral navigation that may confuse the user as they expect to swipe between tabs but are met with "view 2" from the first tab? This section of the Developer Guide is great, read it: http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html

Comment: Let's say I have basically 5 tabs, and the first tab has a list of some information and when the user clicks on one of these list items it is suppose to slide to next layout but every single thing happens in this manner will be still staying in the first tab. The rest of the tabs are containing something else. So I'm actually trying to find a way for paging. As I said I tried view flipper but since it holds all the children in memory, I get out of memory issue. I can still just change the content view when user clicks an item in the list and set it.

Comment: but I want to make it with "slide in" and "slide out" animations as we are able to do it in view flipper.

Comment: Yea, I get you. I don't have the answer without giving a perhaps not great, "use another design paradigm" suggestion! I haven't seen this paradigm being used elsewhere and since I am no navigational/UI guru this would flag to me that I'm doing something the user might not get/the framework doesn't accommodate. Draw a few Screen Maps of what you need to happen and see if something more standard comes out in the wash... http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/wireframing.html

Comment: I found the way, I tried something with fragments and it worked in the way I want. No need to use activities.