# How sliding same activity to left and right

Tags: android, layout, slide, android-sliding

I have one activity. I need slide this activity to right and to left with the same layout that i have in activity. In conclusion i need to execute sliding n times and keep the same layout. It's the same activity with the same layout replicate several times in each slide.

The examples that i view about sliding are very complex. I need a basic example of sliding because i don't know how to start.

I put an image that exemply what i need.
Anybody can help me? 
Thanks by your time and help.

[image]

Comment: This seems very similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a ViewPager for this.

Comment: Use Pager or Fragements !!