# Applying slide in and out animation to view

Tags: java, android, animation

i have a linear layout with webview now i need to apply slide in and slide out animation, do i need to apply animation to webview or linear layout?

If applying on either of them then how to apply because `setInAnimation and setOutAnimation` is not there for both.

How to do it?

Comment: Both are View objects, so it would work on any. Why don't you use this via xml and translate your view?

Comment: @pKs i have code written for that in methods so i wanted to reuse that

Comment: @pKs ok if we can do like that can you let me know how to do that?

Comment: Look at my answer to get your work done.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below animation create the two xml files in your application's `res/anim` folder and paste the below code and then apply it on your webview or linearlayout.

**Slide in:**

```
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate
      android:fromXDelta="100%"
      android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:duration="600" />
 </set>
```

**Slide out**

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <translate
         android:fromXDelta="0%"
         android:toXDelta="-100%"
         android:duration="600" />
  </set>
```

For more details check out [HERE](https://github.com/habibm/Android) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation).

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**make styles.xml and place it in res/values**

```
<style name="MyAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_</item>
```

```
 <style name="SlideAnim">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**make these files and place both of them in res/anim**

**slide_in xml**

```
<translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="700"/>
```

**slide_out xml**

```
<translate
       android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:duration="700" />
```

**And the last step is : inside your xml file where you have placed your LinearLayout or WebView apply style attribute the particular element. In the below example I have done it to LinearLayout.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/SlideAnim"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
....
</LinearLayout>
```