# how to i animate an object in android?

Tags: java, android, animation

Hi i'm looking for a way to animate these little icons i have for an app i'm making. basically i want 3 little icons to slide from the top of the portrait android screen to the bottom continuously and randomly. I have searched a lot so sorry if this is a repeat but i just cant quite find anything i can understand. So far i have Nothing except the images and xml set up. If this is already answered can someone please point me in the right direction. Is there a way to go about this in xml or must i use java? also would it be easier to use a framework such as libgdx with box2D?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [surfaceview](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/648858/Animation-with-SurfaceView) and making your whole screen as a canvas whereas you need to control your objects' position every millisecond, another option is using the `Animation` in android, you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185065/slide-image-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left) it is sliding from left to right and vice versa