# Setting custom animations for fragments

Tags: c#, android, animation, xamarin.android, unhandled-exception

I am trying to make an animation for fragment but when I run app and use animation I get an `Unhandled exception`:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeExeption: Unknown animator name: alpha

My code is:

```
    private void ShowFragment(Android.App.Fragment fragment)
    {
        var trans = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        // this line below set an animation
        trans.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.frag_slide_in, Resource.Animation.frag_slide_out);

        trans.Hide(mCurrentFragment);
        trans.Show(fragment);
        trans.AddToBackStack(null);
        trans.Commit();
        mStackFragment.Push(mCurrentFragment);
        mCurrentFragment = fragment;
    }
```

but my `anim` looks clear

frag_slide_in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/bounce">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="500" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.3"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="500" />

</set>
```

frag_slide_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/anticipate">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:duration="650"/>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.5"
        android:duration="650"/>
</set>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Could you include both anim xmls?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. Done

Comment: you can not directly use animation in fragment, you can do like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760299/android-fragmenttransaction-custom-animation-unknown-animator-name-translate

Comment: Ok, but how to transilate my anim to ObjectAnimator then(like in example in the link)?