# Is there a way to define Fragment transition animations programatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I can use `FragmentTransaction#setCustomAnimation(int, int)` method to define the animations when changing Fragments as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760299/android-fragmenttransaction-custom-animation-unknown-animator-name-translate). However, this approach is limited to animations defined in XML files.

Is there a way to use programmatically defined animations when switching between Fragments?

Comment: Theoretically it should be possible by overriding `onCreateAnimation` to do... something else. You'd have to use a `setCustomAnimation` with a dummy constant to intercept it in the Fragment however. I do not have a sample for this at this time, which is why this is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no such option.

If I'd need to guess, I'd say that the reason is save&restore flow (aka. process death). It's easy to persist IDs of XML resources in Bundle when the app dies and retrieve them later, but it's much more difficult to re-create custom animation objects after the app is re-launched.