# Get animations running on older Android phone

Tags: android, animation, android-2.3-gingerbread

Using the method described in

[Android Left to Right slide animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)

I'm able to perform slide in, slide out transition animations in my app.

On my own phone, a Google LG Nexus 4 running Jelly Bean, it works fine, replacing the default zoom in transition.

However, when I try it on a Huawei G300 running vodafone-branded Gingerbread, I noticed there are no transitions at all, and my custom one doesn't occur either.

Is this an unfixable problem related to the OS, or is there a way I can force enable the animations?

Comment: Are you sure animations are turned on? Settings - Display Settings - Animations

Comment: Ah! that was it! Thank you :) post as answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that animations on the device itself are turned on. The option can be found under Settings - Display Settings - Animations on gingerbread devices.