# How to Create Sliding Buttons in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-switch, android-togglebutton

[image]

I want to create sliding buttons in Android,

When we slide up the light indicator will glow, as we need change image while sliding it.

I have tried with toggle button and switch but its not having sliding effect?

Any suggestion on this.

Comment: You can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation

Comment: Actually I am looking for sliding not for animation.

Comment: Create two versions of this button,one in on state and other in off.Create a toggle button and set the backgrounds through program accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, but toggle button does not have sliding effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use thus library. When you will download it try to set your custom theme and get the solution.
https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0/tree/master/

Comment: I have tried this library, in this its changing text after sliding toggle button, actually I am looking for only toggle button sliding, toggle button it self will change its color on different state.