# Android Left to Right Sliding animation across Activities

Tags: android, android-animation

Right to Left Transition works with this code:

**anim1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

**anim2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-50%p"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

**Code**

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim1, R.anim.anim2);
```

*How do i get Left to Right animation work?*

Comment: check this answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it in this fashion (which is a little different from how right-to-left was done)

**anim3.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

**anim4.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

***Code***

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim3, R.anim.anim4);

Answer (score 0):

**slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_right**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="5000" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="5000" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

**In your acitivty**

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```