# Activity's defaultly loaded fragments' Transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

I have an activity which has a fragment loaded in it's FrameLayout by default. And I have set the fragment's enter and exit transition as follows:

```
HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
homeFragment.setEnterTransition(enter);
homeFragment.setExitTransition(exit);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.vg_full_container,homeFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

But when my activity starts up, the fragment doesn't show any transition. 
However if I make use of FragmentTransaction's `setCustomAnimation()`, the fragment animates into the screen. Also the fragments whose loading is triggered by some event such as `OnClick()` etc., on the same activity, transitions into the screen with`setEnterTransition()` and `setExitTransition()`. But the activity's defaultly loaded fragments don't transition or at least I can't see any transition happening. Also, I have not set any enter and exit transitions on the activity that loads this fragment.

How do I get the defaultly loaded fragments to transition with `setEnterTransition()` and `setExitTransition()`?

Following is the transition XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <slide
       android:duration="400"
       android:slideEdge="left" />
   <targets>
       <target android:excludeId="@id/toolbar"/>
       <target android:excludeId="@id/collapsing_toolbar"/>
       <target android:excludeId="@id/transaction_toolbar"/>
       <target android:excludeId="@id/tab_layout"/>
   </targets>
</transitionSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.vg_full_container,homeFragment)
    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit,
                         R.anim.popenter, R.anim.popexit)
    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

sets animations like this:

[Android Left to Right slide animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)

Comment: I've tried using `setCustomAnimation()` and it works well. But, if I want to use the Android L's Transition frameworks' `setEnterTransition()` and `setExitTransition()` how do I go about it? It doesn't show any Transitions these functions.

Comment: do you want to add animations during in activity transitions or fragment transitions?

Comment: When my activity starts up, I want the fragment to be transitioned as per my XML. But instead, it just pops up without any transition (in my case slide from left). I know `setCustomAnimations()` will animate my fragment's enter and exit. But I can't specify which views to be transitioned/animated and which views to not to animate using `setCustomAnimations()`. As in, I want some of the views in the fragment to slide from left and others to slide from right.

Comment: you can try animations on view only.
like : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/