# android layout (LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) How can I do that?

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, diagonal

How can I do diagonal layout? please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use TranslateAnimation with images.
Use Transparent color as background and put 2 image views to display images. on click of any image use left and right TranslateAnimation on images to exit from the screen.

One more thing from image i can say it is using view overlay pattern. I mean background view is already there it just show/hide functionality with type of data (male/female) passed when user click.

For animation check this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation).

Answer (score 0):

to give you an idea: 
1. create two pngs with alpha (red)  
2. stack them on each other with any layout  
3. adjust paddings/ margins
4. add sliding animations

[see this picture with alphas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eOHW.png)

Answer (score 0):

My Perference is Relative Layout

**RelativeLayout** is a layout manager that helps you arrange your UI elements based on some rule. You can specify things like: align this to parents left edge, place this to the left/right of this elements etc.