# Slider Animation In Gridview Android

Tags: android, animation

I am newbie in Android.
I want to create animation like sliding effect in gridview.For Example I have a gridview which loads the data with the monthview calender.Now I am able to swipe the calender left or right but there is no animation.I want to animate so that it comes in notice to the user of changes in the month when user swipes.Please suggest me the animation which can I implement.

Comment: Have you seen this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation

Comment: I need to use it on single activity