# Slideable panels with nav drawer like animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-transitions

I want to make slideable panels with content lying beneath them. The idea is sort of like this in my mind, but I'm not sure of how to approach this.

[image]

That triangles in the layer 2 can be used to pull or push (slideable animation).

Can anyone drop me a hint or if there's any existing approaches on something like this? If you didn't understand it completely or want some more specific information, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can have a single layout and use the Right-to-Left exit and Left-to-Right animation [as provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35952547/5446940)
2. You can use a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to implement this.

Comment: Looks like that will work for me :D Thanks for the hint. Any idea how I can make it so that I can control the animation with my finger being pressed on it. As if, if I pause my finger half-way (while keeping it pressed), how can I pause the animation right there?

Comment: In that case, you can go with the first approach and use SimpleOnGestureListener. Here's how you can use it: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: And what shall I use to move the object? Translation animation or there's something better in that case?

Comment: You don't need that with SinpleOnGestureListener. You can manually move the view once you start getting events after you implement this:

Comment: @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
         // store position of the initial touch
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
         // calculation and transformation here
            swipeListener.onSwipeMoved(absoluteDx, absoluteDy, viewWidth, viewHeight);
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            swipeListener.onSwipeEnded(viewWidth, viewHeight);
            break;
    }
}

Comment: I think that'd be exactly what I need. Thanks!