# Cannot Slide activity to the left side

Tags: android-activity, android-studio-3.0

I have created 2 activity. In first avtivity has a button which if I click it start second activity. And I set in **AndroidManifest.xml** file `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` for second activity.Now on second activity has back button icon which if I click it will back to first activity. The problem is if I click it slides to the right side.How can I slide it to the left for open first activity?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create anim xml files for entry and exit animation and use overridePendingTransition to perform animation.
See this link [Android Left to Right slide animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)