# How to slide a view out of another view

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a fragment with a navigation menu at the top-left corner. At the start of the activity, I want to gradually slide a view (let's call it *black_view*) out of the menu icon.

**Here's a rough breakdown of how I want the animation to be in accordance with the images below:**

1. Activity starts as the first image with *black_view* being invisible.
2. *black_view* gradually slides out from behind the menu icon length by length until it gets to the point of the second image.

[image: First fragment] >>> [image]

**What I've tried:**

I tried achieving this by using a [TranslateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation). However, the whole length of *black_view* shows up at the start of the animation and this is not what I want. I also saw a couple of sliding animation code snippets like [this](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/left-and-right-slide-animations-on-android-activity-or-view) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57260208/5670752), but they all follow the TranlateAnimation model (with the whole length of *black_view* showing instantly).

How can I achieve this?

PS: If there's any important detail that I failed to add, kindly let me know.

Comment: If you just want the black background to slide gradually, you can use a progress bar that takes up the full length of the view but loads gradually. If the above view is a placeholder for something else, just add a layer view behind your yellow view that will act as a cover as the black view glides into place

Comment: Wow! That's smart thinking @NikosHidalgo. It seems like a lot of stress but I think this is what I'd have to resort to if I don't get a more straightforward approach soon. Many thanks.

Comment: Hopefully, you'll get a more straightforward solution; glad I could provide you with some peace of mind through, knowing that you can achieve the desired effect using alternative means :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done easily with `Slide` transition from `Transition API`. Just use `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition` method then change visibility of black view from `GONE` to `VISIBLE`.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.transition.Slide;
import androidx.transition.Transition;
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewGroup parent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
        parent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                parent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                animate();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void animate() {
        View textView = findViewById(R.id.text);

        Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.LEFT);
        transition.setDuration(2000);
        transition.setStartDelay(1000);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition);

        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image: result]

All classes here are from androix package so code is backward compatible.