# onActivityResult is not called when the back button in ActionBar is clicked

Tags: android, android-actionbar, onactivityresult

Here is my problem:

1. Create a MainActivity. Add a button which will start another activity SecondActivity.

   ```
           Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
           startActivityForResult(i,0);
   ```
2. Inside the SecondActivity, I capture the back button click event and also add a button to return to the first Activity.

   When back button in action bar is clicked:

@Override

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // back button
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            // TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            //finish();
            return false;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

When the button inside activity is clicked:

```
Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        // TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

The onActivityResult in MainActivity is called when I click the button inside the SecondActivity, but it's never been called if I click the back button in Actionbar of SecondActivity. Can anybody tell me why? Thanks

Comment: uncomment finish() in onOptionsItemSelected() and try once...

Comment: I tried with finish() or without finish(). Both don't work.

Comment: 'return true;' is the real keyword for that issue. If you miss that,application doesn't close properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code which is working:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // back button
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I guess the finish() will close the current Activity, and return true inform that action has been processed. (The default back action seems to be different from finish().)

Comment: The onCreate event in MainActivity will be triggered if I return false in onOptionsItemSelected. The MainActivity was recreated. I guess that is the reason why the onActivityResult is never been called.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the same result with my own answer. Any difference between  finish() and onBackPressed()?

Comment: @bagusflyer It worked for me so thought may be on yours..but worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer is [Gopal Rao code in the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20355292/2270059). Its worked for me. This is a copy of his solution:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
          Intent result = new Intent((String) null);
          result.putExtra("SOME_CONSTANT_NAME", true);
          setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
          finish();
          return true;
       } 
       else {
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }
```