# onActivityResult method is not being called

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I'm having a problem in my android application. I don't know why 'onActivityResult' method is not being called when 'Up navigation' button from action bar is pressed. I think I've done everything properly:

Parent activity launch child activity with 'startActivityForResult' method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ParentActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
```

Parent activity has overridden 'onActivityResult' method.

> ```
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
> {
>    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);   
>    if (data != null && requestCode == 1000)
>    {
>         Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
>         Boolean rc = extras.getBoolean(MyConstants.INTENT_EXTRA_RESULT);
>         if (rc)
>         {
>             .......
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Child activity has overridden 'onOptionsItemSelected' and calls 'NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask'.

> ```
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
>   {
>     if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
>     {
>         Intent result = new Intent((String)null);
>         result.putExtra(MyConstants.INTENT_EXTRA_RESULT, true);
>         setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
>         NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);          
>         return true;
>     }           
>     else
>     {
>         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>     }
> }
> ```

Child activity has overriden 'finish' method. This method set a result.

```
public void finish() 
{
   Intent result = new Intent((String)null);
   result.putExtra(Constantes.INTENT_EXTRA_HAY_QUE_RECALCULAR, hayQueRecalcular);               
   setResult(RESULT_OK, result);

   super.finish();
}
```

I'm not sure why 'onActivityResult' method is not being called.

What I've observed is that child activity is not being finished ('finish' method is not being called) when 'Up navigation' button from action bar is pressed. However it is called when back button (hardware button) is pressed.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what is your request code that you are giving while using startActivityForResult(Intent,int)? is it a positive integer?

Comment: Check the launch mode of you parent activity. See here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6002384/713778

Comment: Yes, it is a positive integer (1000).

Comment: I haven't defined launch mode of my parent activity

Comment: Please post your code which starts the activity, and handles the activity result

Comment: I've posted the code you asked me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your child Activity is just on the top of your Parent Activity, no need of this method

```
 NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

write like

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent result = new Intent((String) null);
        result.putExtra(MyConstants.INTENT_EXTRA_RESULT, true);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

finish your Child Activity when home button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Then I don't understand what 'navigateUpFromSameTask method' is for. I thought it was to navigate to the parent activity. Android documentation says: "To navigate up when the user presses the app icon, you can use the NavUtils class's static method, navigateUpFromSameTask(). When you call this method, it finishes the current activity and starts (or resumes) the appropriate parent activity."

Comment: Thanks, now works but I still doesn't understand why 'NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)' doesn't finish the child activity.

Comment: @Eduardo Don't know exactly about behaviour of NavUtils. I think it directly removes Activity from task.

Comment: what if u have a second child activity in between? how do you send the result to the parent?