# Activity finish animation on Android Wear?

Tags: wear-os

I'm trying to make a activity finish animation on Android Wear. I tried solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330675/how-can-i-add-an-animation-to-the-activity-finish) topic, but it's not working on AW. Do anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm also having trouble with this on Android Wear - did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: No, but I noticed that the start animation of activity is possible to change. Still having trouble with this finish animation.