# Remove animation on fragment .finish()

Tags: android, android-fragments

When my user clicks on the `About` item in my menu, I launch an `AboutFragment` that displays all the necessary information.

In order to go back to the calling activity, I have set a back arrow with

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

When my user clicks it I call `finish()`, but this causes a small animation where my Activity replaces the fragment and lifts up.

Would there be a way to have my activities view replace my fragment with no animation?

Answer (score 2):

Animation is caused due to fragment transaction you can use this to remove it.

```
 fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330675/how-can-i-add-an-animation-to-the-activity-finish).

```
finish();
TrakrActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

I override a pending transition and sets it to nothing (0,0).