# How to handle animations when start/exit an Android.Provider.Settings activity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, animation, android-activity

I'm wondering if it's possible to handle animations for Android.Provider.Settings?

Below is the code to start the Android.Provider.Settings.ActionWifiSettings activity with animations, but after, i don't know how to set animations when the user get back to the previous activity (by pressing the back button).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionWifiSettings);
this.StartActivity(intent);
OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.abc_slide_in_bottom, Resource.Animation.abc_fade_out);
```

I'm working on a xamarin.android.

Thank you.

Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add an animation to the activity finish()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330675/how-can-i-add-an-animation-to-the-activity-finish)

Comment: The accepted answer from there might help, particularly in combination with the comment from eugeneek about overriding `finish()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add animation in OnResume method of your activity.For do this you must override OnResume method and add animation

```
protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.abc_slide_in_bottom, 
        Resource.Animation.abc_fade_out);


    }
```