# Android Left to Right window slide animation API 4 and higher

Tags: android, android-animation

I am going to be using the Action Bar compatibility in version 1.6. I need the "home" button to show the main menu (which is going to be a different activity, not a sidebar) but I want the slide animation to be from left to right when the activity starts.

I found a question that is similar to what I need, but the solution described there is not supported in v1.6.
[Left to Right Slide Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151591/android-left-to-right-slide-animation)

Comment: I also looked at this one but it seems to be limited to predefined animations in the OS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to use reflection and use the "overridingTransitionPending" method if available. Not the ideal solution but it works.