# How to implement Flipboard ipad page turning animation for view flipper in android?

Tags: android, viewflipper

Trying to implement page turning animation exactly as the flipboard ipad app. I have referred some blogs and following links :

[Android: How to make the flip animation for android activity, as like iphone flip horizontal from left to right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499767/android-how-to-make-the-flip-animation-for-android-activity-as-like-iphone-fli)

[How to do page flip/turn/curl effect in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839117/how-to-do-page-flip-turn-curl-effect-in-android)

but able to implement only the normal page curl effect. Is there a way to implement the page turning effect for view flipper similar to flipboard ipad app in android? The flipboard ipad app animation is as in the following link :

[Flipboard ipad app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2vpvEDS00o&feature=youtube_gdata_player)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://oreilly.com/javascript/archive/flashhacks.html) is a good tutorial that explain this principle(it's implemented with Flex, but works with android too).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:
http://openaphid.github.com/blog/2012/05/21/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android/

It may not meet your requirement as it uses OpenGL ES.

Comment: yes, but i was asking for the flipboard ipad app. +1 and thank you for the useful info.