# How to implement page turn over animation in android using custom views

Tags: android

how can i implement page turning animation in android by using view flipper or view pager or even a custom view for webpages. i have searched a lot but could not find a detailed tutorial on it. i have looked into many codes but they all have limitations, some only show images and some only text

i have already tried this link
[How to implement Flipboard ipad page turning animation for view flipper in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662344/how-to-implement-flipboard-ipad-page-turning-animation-for-view-flipper-in-andro)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're gonna need to go with an OpenGL solution here.
I've worked on a book reading solution, and used a package which i found was really good:
https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Keep in mind that everything this page curler displays must be a bitmap, so im not sure it'll be good for you needs.

If you're ok with using a static "cardboard" page animation (one that doesnt curl), you could probably use canvas for it, and that would enable you to animate views rather than just bitmaps.

Here's a link to get you started on that:
http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/3d-rotations-on-views

Hope this helps :)

Comment: cannot i create a custom view that uses a webpage instead of bitmap for page curl animation

Comment: that means you can only use bitmaps for page curl animation not a view...thanks for your help