# How to access the activity animation programatically?

Tags: android

Different Android devices use different animations to move between activities. How do I access the one that is currently being used, from my own code?

Answer (score -2):

you should override `overridePendingTransition(int , int)` inside your activity.
[Activity transition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android)

Edit:

well, I think this is what you want http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

Comment: You're telling me how to set the animation for activities, which is not what I want. I want to access the default animation (so I can use it elsewhere in my app, for consistency).