# Own transition effect from activity to activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

I made a layout animation, it is a compound animation, made in code.
More less it works a bit like slide in / slide out through upper screen edge, the thing that is interesting me, is to see new activity right after that animation, so during it I can see the new view that I`m going to.

Comment: This might be the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to do what i wanted i had to use fragments from support library v4, i simply put view as overlay of fragment holder, achieving that after animation i can se fragment which is below my animated overlay, i found no way to do this on standrad Activities