# Android fill part of screen with menu

Tags: android

I am developing an app for Android, and would like to have a menu button in the top left corner, above a webview. When this button is pressed, I want a menu filling *almost* the entire screen to slide in from the side, as in Evernote's android app. How is this most easily achieved?

I have googled quite a bit without finding an answer, all help is appreciated.[image: Before button pressed]
[image: After button pressed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different libraries you could use to implement a sliding menu like this.  I'm currently using [this library](https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation) which is very easy to implement.  It also uses ActionBarSherlock which is included.

Answer (score 0):

The menu is probably programmed using ActionbarSherlock and the transition between activities is explained here:
[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android)

Without any code this is all we can do for you. Hope this might help.

Comment: Its sliding drawer. You can use this library: https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer