# Android custom transitions between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I would like to know the best way to do custom transitions betweens activities on Android. 
I don't want to do simple transition like this: http://ahdidou.com/blog/customize-android-activities-transition/#.UvJhvdx8uct
I would like to use some of my views of my current activity, transition to the newer one and blend my views with my new activity.

Example: Fade out the current activity while keeping desired views visible, fade in the new activity and move my views at some place on the new activity then make them disappear.

Is there anything build in, or should I code something totally custom?

Clarification: I'm coming from iOS, in iOS 7 Apple introduced an API to do custom transition, it provide an easy way to access the current displayed viewController, the upcoming viewController and also provide a containerView, which is a sandbox where you can add, and animate your views during your transition. 
What I want to do on Android is close to that, I want to transition between 2 activities while showing an "in transition" view on the screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity transition in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android)

Comment: Not at all, I don't want to do fade in/out simple transition, what I'm asking is a little more complexe.

Comment: The duplicate question answers in more detail than just fade-in/out. Can you be more clear in what you are looking to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any auto-magic ways of doing this, but here's one way that probably would work:

1. Disable animation by including an intent flag NoAnimation when you start the new activity. Then re-use the layout from the original activity in the pushing activity. Then animate the views as you want them to be.

Never tried it but I will here in a bit and see where it gets me.