# Android. Transition activity or turn activity

Tags: android, android-activity, transition, onpause

How determine transition to other activity (when opened other activity same application) or turn activity (roll up activity, when user pressed HOME button) ? I think use OnPause and onStop for saving current state of the app in global variable (in App class, for example), but OnPause call always when call onStop

Comment: Look here on how to do it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android

Comment: use overridePendingTransition? But how I can catch this event?

Comment: http://www.vardhan-ds.co.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html