# Need to Animate image button

Tags: android, animation

I have my Android app with a login activity . when the user gets logged in i need another activity which contains four image buttons and the main need is that when the activity comes up the **buttons must slide** to the middle from the right side . Can anyone help me with the codes

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.make anim folder and create xml with name slide_right.xml and put the below content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="500" />
```

Step 2.Into the onCreate() method of  your MainActivity class, load animation and set it to  your view buttons

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_right);
yourbutton.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: is this only for buttons or for the whole activity .. but here in this code where th button item is specified ??

Comment: yes this for the button which you have specified to be loaded from right side of the screen.First find the id of the buttons and setAnimation to that as i have specified yourbuttonid.startAnimation(animation). you can override the screen transitions.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can also use View Flipper

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/myFlipper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateFirstView="true"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="500"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"
    android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out" >
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/myImage" />
</ViewFlipper>
```