# Tansitioning between activities

Tags: android

Before I started working with transitions in Android, I was under the impression that transitions was possible from one activity to another. In other words, when you launch an activity from another activity, you could provide a transition with animation.

After just learning about transitions, this does not appear possible. The documentation indicates that transitions occur within the same activity. In other words, transitions just let you rearrange the view for the current activity.

So is it correct that transitions are limited to just a specific activity, or is it possible to transition to another activity? I can imagine the benefits of transitioning to a different activity, the most important being that when multiple developers are working on a project, each can work on their own activities without having to combine functionality into a single activity in order to create animated transitions.

Comment: so you want animation for views or between activities?

Comment: I just want to know whether it's possible to create an animated transition from one activity to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for 
["activity transition in android"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android)

cheers!

P.S:Check this other link if you wanna have a multipleviewswitcher :) http://www.malmstein.com/blog/2014/07/09/your-forms-dont-need-to-be-ugly-part-3/

Comment: That post is 4 years old. The Transition Manager framework for material design was only introduced with API 19. I believe the post you are referring to does only fading from one activity to another but with a completely different API that has less functionality than the transitioning framework in API 19. Still, you answered my question and animated transitions between activities is possible. It does raise the question though why Google would create a new transitioning framework that only works on a single activity.