# How to combine fading and translation animations in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to achieve an activity transition from Splash screen to Main activity in which :

- Splash screen : fades out and goes to left
- Main activity : fades in and moves up.

Kindly tell if this is even possible ?

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31740347/9473786

Comment: Thank You so much ! Worked like a charm.